# void ordenar( String[] nombres ) Ordena la matriz alfabéticamente

Tags: java

Buenas tardes compañer@s, a ver si me podéis ayudar:

Como comento en el enunciado el ejercicio que tengo que hacer, según funciones, nada de encapusulamiento. Estamos partiendo casi desde 0 en java. Es un vector con String que lo tengo que mostrar en pantalla ordenado.
El código que he levantado es el siguiente:

```
    package Ejercicios;


    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Ejercicio8_Arrays {
    
        static void ordenar( String[] nombres ){
            String aux="";
            boolean ordenado;
            do{
                ordenado=true;
                for(int indice=0; indice<nombres[0].length()-1; indice++){
                    if(nombres[indice].charAt(0)>nombres[indice+1].charAt(0)) {
                     //Aqui es donde vamos ordenando
                        nombres[indice] = nombres[indice+1]; 
                        nombres[indice+1]=aux;
                        ordenado = false;   
                
                    }
                
                }
        
            }while(ordenado==false);
        
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String[]m=new String[]{ "Alboka", "Tin whistle", "Gaita", "Acordeon", "Trompeta", "Armonica" };
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));
            ordenar(m);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m)); 
        }

    }
```

En pantalla me aparece el vector de String desordenado pero a la hora de llamar a la función ordenar me aparecen los siguientes errores

Comment: > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
 at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:711)
 at Ejercicios.Ejercicio8_Arrays.ordenar(Ejercicio8_Arrays.java:16)
 at Ejercicios.Ejercicio8_Arrays.main(Ejercicio8_Arrays.java:35)

Answer (score 2):

Para ordenar alfabeticamente tu Array simplemente usa el mètodo [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-),

> [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) Ordena la matriz especificada de objetos en orden
> ascendente, de acuerdo con el orden natural de sus elementos.

ejemplo :

```
 String[] nombres = new String[]{"Alboka", "Tin whistle", "Gaita", "Acordeon", "Trompeta", "Armonica"};
 Arrays.sort(nombres);
 System.out.println("nombres ordenados: " + Arrays.toString(nombres));
```

salida:

```
nombres ordenados: [Acordeon, Alboka, Armonica, Gaita, Tin whistle, Trompeta]
```

Este serìa el còdigo de tu ejemplo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Ejercicio8_Arrays {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    static void ordenar(String[] nombres) {
         
        Arrays.sort(nombres);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String[] m = new String[]{"Alboka", "Tin whistle", "Gaita", "Acordeon", "Trompeta", "Armonica"};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));
        ordenar(m);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));
    }

}
```

Tu array originalmente es:

```
[Alboka, Tin whistle, Gaita, Acordeon, Trompeta, Armonica]
```

Al ser ordenado alfabeticamente se obtendrìa como salida:

```
[Acordeon, Alboka, Armonica, Gaita, Tin whistle, Trompeta]
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocupar [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) de java.util

Tú método quedaría.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[]m=new String[]{ "Alboka", "Tin whistle", "Gaita", "Acordeon", "Trompeta", "Armonica" };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));
    Arrays.sort(m);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m)); 
}
```